# SharePoint Search, enable all filetypes

Tags: 2010, search

How can I enable all filetypes to be indexed with SharePoint search? I bassically want to add a wildcard somehow to allow all filetypes to be crawled, at least the filenames indexed for all files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such wildcard option you can:

1. Manually add each filetype you want to index via Central Admin or
2. Write a PowerShell script to do it use something like this to add
   with a loop or something:

   Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication | New-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlExtension -Name YourExtension

Comment: This is very unfortunate for us. We were planning on using SharePoint search for all our officeshares but now we get very restricted. I know we couldn't search the content on most files but filenames and meta data would have been sufficient for the other filetypes. Now we need to provide the users with two solutions. One within SharePoint for searching content and another one for searching the filenames and metadata for all the files.

Comment: You can still use search as you want, you just need to add these unknown file types to the file type list and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add any filetype as Toni explains. Just remember that you also need to find and install the appropriate ifilters on the index server. Otherwise the contents of the files is not indexed. But the filenames will indeed be indexed no matter what as you require.